# Improve App run time for android

Tags: java, android, runtime, signal-processing

I wrote a speech enhancement code for an andriod App. Algorithm runs on 256 size frames of voice samples. On my PC the code runs per Frame about 5ms while on my Nexsus5 it more like 50ms making the speech enhancement on a 30sec long recording run for over two minutes, on my PC enhancing the whole audio file takes under a minute. I am looking to improve run time any where I can.
I am attaching the code that runs per frame which is where I see biggest increase in run time.

```
for(int j = 0; j < Consts.NUM_OF_CLUSTERS; j++)
    {
        tmp_log_h=0;
        for(int k = 0; k < Consts.SIZE_OF_SEMPELS_IN_CHUNCK; k++)
        {

            f_X = (1/FastMath.sqrt(2*FastMath.PI*sigmaSqr.get(j).get(k)))*FastMath.exp(-(FastMath.pow(NoisySignal[k] - mue.get(j).get(k),2))/(2*sigmaSqr.get(j).get(k)));// equation (3)
            F_X=(0.500 + 0.5*Erf.erf((NoisySignal[k] - mue.get(j).get(k))/(FastMath.sqrt(2*sigmaSqr.get(j).get(k)))));// equation (6)

            if(j==0)
            {
                g_pdf_Y[k]=1/FastMath.sqrt(2*FastMath.PI*Noise_sigmaSqr.get(k))*FastMath.exp(-(FastMath.pow(NoisySignal[k] - Noise_mu.get(k),2))/(2*Noise_sigmaSqr.get(k)));// equation (4)
                G_cdf_Y[k]=(0.500 + 0.5*Erf.erf((NoisySignal[k] - Noise_mu.get(k))/(FastMath.sqrt(2*Noise_sigmaSqr.get(k)))));// equation (5)
            }

            tmp_R_samples = (f_X/F_X);// equation (12.5)

            if(j==0)
            {
                R_noise[k]=g_pdf_Y[k]/G_cdf_Y[k]; // equation (12.5)
            }

            Roe[j][k] = 1/(1 + (R_noise[k]/tmp_R_samples));
            X_hat[j][k] = NoisySignal[k]*Roe[j][k]+ (mue.get(j).get(k))*(1 - Roe[j][k]) - (sigmaSqr.get(j).get(k))*((f_X*R_noise[k])/(f_X + F_X*R_noise[k]));
            tmp_h_first=(f_X*G_cdf_Y[k] + F_X*g_pdf_Y[k]);// equation (7.5)             
            tmp_log_h += FastMath.log(tmp_h_first); // equation (7.5)
        }


        Log_h_second[j]=tmp_log_h;
        Log_h_final_vecotr[j]=FastMath.log(c.get(j)) + Log_h_second[j];
    }


    Double maxVi = MathHelpers.findMax(Log_h_final_vecotr);

    double sumExp = 0.0;

    for(int j = 0; j < Consts.NUM_OF_CLUSTERS; j++)
    {
        sumExp +=(FastMath.exp(Log_h_final_vecotr[j] - maxVi));// equation (18)
        System.out.println(sumExp);
    }

    Log_h_final = maxVi + FastMath.log(sumExp);


    for(int j = 0; j < Consts.NUM_OF_CLUSTERS; j++)
    {
        Log_q[j]=FastMath.log(c.get(j)) + Log_h_second[j] - Log_h_final;
        q[j]=(FastMath.exp(Log_q[j]));// equation (10)
    }


    for(int k = 0; k < Consts.SIZE_OF_SEMPELS_IN_CHUNCK; k++)
    {
        Double temp_X_estimate = 0.0;

        for(int j = 0; j < Consts.NUM_OF_CLUSTERS; j++)
        {
            temp_X_estimate += (X_hat[j][k]*q[j]);
        }   

        X_estimate[k]=temp_X_estimate;// equation (9)
    }
```

Comment: This looks like a question that more properly belongs in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: 1. Run it in C vis JNI (see NDK) or 2. look into Renderscript

Comment: What algorithm are you using? Is there a better optimized algorithm? It looks like something copied from the manual but maybe there's something else that's optimized for numerical processing.